# How to flat a IEnumerable by 2 Values?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
class AgeClass
{
    string[] Names {get;set;}
    int Age {get;set;}
}

...

IEnumerable<AgeClass> myList = ...; // a few instances of AgeClass
```

now i want to get (out of myList) a

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,int>>
```

with a Pair of Name and Age. How to do this easily?

Comment: I must say I did not expect Sheldon Cooper to have such easy questions :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
myList.SelectMany(
     x=> x.Names.Select(
          z => new KeyValuePair<string,int>(z,x.Age)));
```

Note that you must be aware that linq is creating a query - each time you enumerate this collection new one will be created based on current state of `myList`. To remove this effect simply add `.ToList()` to the end of this line.

Answer (score 1):

Using a query linq syntax:

```
var result = from el in myList
             from n in el.Names
               select new KeyValuePair<string, int>(n, el.Age);
```